# Type error: 'Modal' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js project for bigcommerce. When i run the command `yarn build` i got the error

> Type error: 'Modal' cannot be used as a JSX component.
>
> Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<ModalProps, any,
> any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.

```
const Modal = dynamic(() => import('@components/ui/Modal'), {
  ...dynamicProps,
  ssr: false,
})

const ModalView: React.FC<{ modalView: string; closeModal(): any }> = ({
  modalView,
  closeModal,
}) => {
  return (
    <Modal onClose={closeModal}>
      {modalView === 'LOGIN_VIEW' && <LoginView />}
      {modalView === 'SIGNUP_VIEW' && <SignUpView />}
      {modalView === 'FORGOT_VIEW' && <ForgotPassword />}
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Is being caused by the new version 18 of @types/react support.

I've tracked it down to dependencies using `"@types/react": "*"` which in turn is being resolved to version 18 of @types/react. Even though I have also explicitly set @types/react to 17 in the project.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment this is happening due to new release of @types/react to accommodate changes in react v18 (don't you just love it when a new package is released and it wreaks havoc on your codebase when you didn't do anything! That's what happens when you don't respect semantic versioning... ).

One way to fix the issue is to use `resolutions` in `yarn` (or overrides in `npm` I think is the equivalent) by setting:

```
    "resolutions": {
        "@types/react": "<18.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "<18.0.0"
    },
```

You will need to blow away your lock file and node modules. And then install everything again from scratch.

Also, just incase, if you're using lerna/workspaces then the resolutions need to be done at the root level not in package.json of a workspace package. I believe there is an outstanding issue on github to address this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pnpm you can use pnpm.overrides which should be added on the root package.json

```
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "@types/react": "<18.0.0",
      "@types/react-dom": "<18.0.0"
    }
  }
```